# Finding the p-value of an ANOVA table

Tags: statistics

I am given an ANOVA table, with printed R code:

```
> names(mydata)
[1] "AgeGroup" "Cholesterol"

> favstats(Cholesterol)
min Q1 median Q3 max mean 
142 191.25 211 249.25 289 216.8571

> favstats(Cholesterol~AgeGroup)
     sd  n missing
38.8327 28       0
   AgeGroup  min    Q1   median     Q3  max      mean        sd  n  missing
1  F_over50  161  185.5     201  243.0  265  212.0000  40.19121  7  0
2 F_under50  162  184.0     197  207.5  221  194.7143  19.93919  7  0
3  M_over50  192  240.0     253  272.5  289  251.2857  32.36106  7  0
4 M_under50  142  190.5     209  231.5  271  209.4286  40.97502  7  0



> a1<-lm(Cholesterol~AgeGroup)
> anova(a1)
          Df  Sum Sq  Mean Sq  F value   Pr(>F) 
AgeGroup  (A)   (C)     (E)      (G)      (H) *
Residuals (B)   (D)     (F)

---
Signif. codes: 0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

The following code was printed, so I don't have access to the actual data set to run R code on.  I need to calculate these values by hand.  I calculated all of them except (H), the p-value.

How do I find the p-value of the ANOVA table without using technology?  I'm thinking I might need to use an F-value table, but I was wondering if there was another way.

Any help would be appreciated; thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test statistic follows an F-ratio distribution and the cumulative distribution function can be found either using a table (as you mentioned) or using the beta regularized function. If you do the latter you will likely need a special computer module in your favorite language to evaluate it.